# PHP weight SQL results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table in which I store a column (called `tickets`), and the `tickets` value can be any number.

What I would like to do is have a mysql query that selects all of the rows from the column, sorts them in descending order, and then use PHP to "weight" the results of the query, so that the rows with the highest `tickets` value have a higher chance of being chosen.

That sounds pretty confusing. Essentially, the higher number of `tickets` a row has, the higher chance it has of being picked.

Is there anyway to do this using procedural mysqli to select the rows and PHP to get the ticket?

Comment: mysqli has nothing to do with the way SQL gets executed

Comment: I'll keep my clothes on, thanks

Comment: What "chance" are you talking about? If you `ORDER BY tickets DESC`, the row with highest value of that column will be first in the result set, but "chance" is not up to `ORDER BY` clause ;)

Comment: MySQL is used to get the information, php is used to process it. Use MySQL to get the rows, use PHP to select the ticket randomly based on your requirements.

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make more sense. And can anyone explain Strawberry's comment?

Comment: @Kidd396 Strawberry's comment is in response to your use of "bare with me" rather than "bear with me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the query itself is not going to get you what you want, which is essentially a weighted random selection.  It sounds like what you need to do is to select all the rows and place them in say a numerically indexed array, with rows that have X number of tickets placed in the array X times at different indexes.  Then just randomly select a number between 0 and [ARRAY_SIZE - 1] to determine the row you select.

So query might look like:

```
SELECT id, tickets FROM table
```

Where `id` would be the primary key for the table.

And the code might look like this:

```
// your DB query logic here
// proceed with following code only if non-empty result set is returned

// build the array
$selection_array = array();
while($row = /* your DB row fetch mechanism here */) {
    $temp = array_fill(0, (int)$row['tickets'], $row['id']);
    $selection_array = array_merge($selection_array, $temp);
}

// select value from array
$random = rand(0, count($selection_array) - 1);
$selected_id = $selection_array[$random];
```

Comment: This works exactly like how I wanted it to, but it is a bit slow for filtering through thousands of rows from the table and millions of tickets.

Comment: @Kidd396 Operationally, this should take O(n) where n is the number of id's returned from the query.  The number of tickets should not matter unless you are joining another table to determine that ticket count as part of this query.  If you know that you only want to limit selection to say top 100 or so ticket counts, then you could certainly add a LIMIT clause to the query (but this would introduce need to ORDER BY as well - I was trying to skip that).

Answer (score 0):

Well, just an idea... ;)

You could multiply `tickets` value by a random one...

```
... ORDER BY tickets*RAND() DESC
```

This way you'd get the records ordered by not the tickets number per say, but a modified number...

`RAND()` will return a different random value for every row examined, but since the original number is higher, chances are the result will also be higher.